# When animating in Android, how can I use a SurfaceView as well as XML?

Tags: android, xml

To clarify a bit, I would like to make a simple animation [like in this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUmId0rwsBQ&index=67&list=PL023BC9408BAFEC0C), but I had already designed the appearance of my app in XML. Is there a way I can display the animation behind my XML file so that it shows behind my buttons, or would I have to start from scratch and design it all in Surface View?

Comment: The graphical operations used in a SurfaceView have nothing to do with xml layout files, so, yes, it sounds like you'll have to start over.

Comment: @MikeM. So there's no way to do animations and display my xml layout?

Comment: Oh, I think I misunderstood your question. You can use your existing layout, and just add a SurfaceView as one of its components, just like adding a Button, a TextView, etc.

Comment: @MikeM. Oh good, scared me a bit. Where should I place it, so that it doesn't display over top of my buttons and such?

Comment: As long as your layout is setup so that none of the Views overlap, you should be able to put it anywhere you want.

Comment: @MikeM. You've been a big help. Thanks